# How do they return to their own time in Twelve Monkeys?

Tags: 12-monkeys-1995

In the film Twelve Monkeys, they show Cole traveling back to the past but not how he returns to his time. Is the process ever explained?

Comment: downvoter identify yourself and your reasons !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't explained in detail in the movie. But IIRC, the scientists control Cole through a device in his tooth. The second time they try to shift him to 1996, they mistakenly place him in the middle of World War 1 and then are able to move him forward by 80+ years to 1996. We can therefore assume that they can control Cole's position in time remotely.